# How can rustfmt be configured to emit tabs not these indenting spaces?

Tags: rust

Why is rustfmt emitting indenting spaces in the below code example, and how can it be configured to stop?

I have the following code:

```
fn main() {
    if {
        let to_comp = true;
        if to_comp { true } else { false }
    } {
        println!("true");
    }
}
```

which rustfmt formats as (*I have replaced all the tabs with `--->` and the indenting spaces with `_` to illustrate the indentation*):

```
fn main() {
--->if {
--->--->___let to_comp = true;
--->--->___if to_comp { true } else { false }
--->--->__} {
--->--->println!("true");
--->}
}
```

My `rustfmt.toml` for the above code:

```
tab_spaces = 4
hard_tabs = true
array_layout = "Block"
reorder_imports = true
newline_style = "Unix"
spaces_within_angle_brackets = false
spaces_within_parens = false
spaces_within_square_brackets = false
fn_args_layout = "Block"
fn_call_style = "Block"
fn_return_indent = "WithArgs"
fn_brace_style = "SameLineWhere"
generics_indent= "Block"
item_brace_style = "PreferSameLine"
where_layout = "Horizontal"
where_pred_indent = "Block"
where_style = "Rfc"
```

I would like to know if there exists a `rustfmt` configuration option that will emit only tabs for indenting. So the code would be formatted like:

```
fn main() {
--->if {
--->--->let to_comp = true;
--->--->if to_comp { true } else { false }
--->--->} {
--->--->println!("true");
--->}
}
```

Comment: Your example Rust code is not well formed: the first `if` is missing the condition. Are you sure `rustfmt` doesn't emit any errors? Apart from that: what do you want to show us with your example code? Is that the code you want to format or is it the formatting you consider "correct"? In the latter case: ... why? Why those 3-space and 2-space indent? And lastly: while we all are still using text based editors, we do care about format consistency. Obeying the rules from the community (4 space indent) is **far more important** than using the format you like best. You just have to get used to it.

Comment: In the interest of avoiding false consensus, note that not all Rust programmers use a 4 space indent convention. Some of them just aren't as...outspoken as others ;)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Once the `_`s and `--->` are removed the code is perfectly valid. Rust allows for blocks to return a type(this is notated by the lack of a semicolon where one would normal be) hence `{ true }` is `true`. In my example above the first if statement depends on the condition returned by the following block. As to following the rules of the community: I can follow them by running a standard `cargo fmt` before uploading. I don't have to use the standard style while editing.

Comment: @Shepmaster The code is not "syntactically invalid Rust code". also the question has as much detail as have about the task. I do not know what way or even if there is a way to format this code so indenting spaces are removed, so I cannot provide a example of what that `rustfmt` setting would modify the output to. Would changing the title from "these space" to "these indenting spaces" help clarify?

Comment: @Avi You seem to wish for `rustfmt` to perform a very specific form of indentation. Consider writing an input code and the desired output code by hand. If you cannot do this, then the question is inevitably ill-formed.

Comment: @Avi I see now. If nothing else, that's certainly a *very unusual* way to organize your code, getting close to obfuscated code territory. I'd generally recommend that you store that as a variable instead of placing the block there. Were I code reviewing it, I'd certainly reject it ^_^. However, your question can still be improved by providing **both** the input source code and the desired output code. That way there can be no ambiguity about what exactly it is you want the formatter to do and a potential answerer can feel that much more confident about their answer being useful.

Comment: @Shepmaster I have updated the question. Are there any other ways in which it can be improved.

Comment: @Avi: I have further tweaked the question; if you do not like my edit, you can (1) further edit or (2) revert it by clicking on the "edited ... ago" link which leads you to the post history and selecting a revision to revert to.

Comment: @Avi: I'm sorry, my bad for saying your code is invalid Rust! :( But the fact that a few experienced Rust programmers incorrectly parsed your code as invalid in their heads, is a clear indicator that the formatting is unusual (or even not idiomatic). I agree with Shepmaster that you would want to save your boolean condition in a variable and write the `if`-head in a single line. But thanks a lot for improving your quesiton! :)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt It is worth noting this code was derived from real code to demonstrate a formatting issue. This type of pattern is unusual, but it  can be useful in certain cases where storing context is not ideal or for a number of other reasons that can not be appropriately expressed here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `control_style = "Rfc"`. The output will be like the following:

```
fn main() {
    if {
        let to_comp = true;
        if to_comp { true } else { false }
    }
    {
        println!("true");
    }
}
```